# Lotus Notes: Network resource unavailable error

Tags: windows-update, lotus-notes

Let me start by saying English is not my first language, so I apologize if my question doesn't make sense or is just unreadable.

---

So Lotus Notes seems to have a weird problem after Windows updates(It might have have something to do with update KB4284848)

everytime users open their browser(Chrome), after a minute or so they get a pop-up in Notes saying:

**The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable, Click OK to try again or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package.**

I have tried to replicate the error, but no luck.

I also searched the web for any information regarding this particular error but I only get post that have nothing to do with my problem or are a few years old.

---

I know that this isn't much to go on, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT a problem with your Lotus Notes software. This is a known bug with Google Chrome Version 67 and above.

This bug is approved to be chrome issue 860537 and a fix is [announced for tomorrow.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=860537#c74):

Comment: Thanks. I started seeing this a couple of days ago, too. Hadn't started looking into it, as it seemed to be minimally annoying and apparently harmless.